# The list of projected GDP in the past?

Tags: data-request, economics, gdp

I would like to get any data that predicted GDP in the past (e.g. the projected 2015 GDP that was released in 2000). I don't mind what organization the data was released by, as long as it is prominent (e.g. UN, OECD, IMF, or WB) because I just want to know how the future GDP prediction diverges.

Can I download those datasets for free?

Comment: Where have you looked so far for these data? 
http://www.worldbank.org/en/publication/global-economic-prospects/archives seems to have some of this, granted not in machine readable format

Comment: @Skram I searched on all the site mentioned above, plus some google results. Do you imply that the data is written in the PDF you cited?

Comment: I hope you find a better source but the data does seem to be available (yet locked up in PDF), yeah. I might have misread though

Comment: Survey of Professional Forecasters https://www.philadelphiafed.org/research-and-data/real-time-center/survey-of-professional-forecasters/